# Can I drag someone off a cliff while I have him grappled?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, grapple, forced-movement

After I grapple a foe can I drag him off a cliff or do I have to push/shove him at the end?

Comment: Related [Does grappling an enemy into an AOE also subject the grappler to the AOE?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/71218)

Comment: I have an answer for this question that doesn't apply as an answer to the question this duplicates.

Comment: Do not answer in comments.  An answer in comments has been deleted.